# Leaflet with multiple polylines elements leads to huge HTML

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I'm building a leaflet map on R having multiple layers that are controlled by `addLayersControl`.  **Every layer as the same spatial information**, so only the data associated to each polylines changes. The idea is to have a basic map, where the user decide which data field is display.  I succeeded at making the map, however I noticed that the size of the `html` file produced is huge.

In my actual context, making the map with only one layer leads to a ~20mb file.  However, if I add one field it gets to ~40mb and three layer ~60mb.  So it seems to me that the `html` produced is loading the same shapefile 3 times instead of simply using one shapefile and linking it a data frame of some sort.

Am I stock with this behavior of leaflet or is there a way to file size inflation in my context?  I may not have programmed my leaflet the *better* way...

I've made a reproducible example to show the problem.  It uses a small shapefile so the size problem is not dramatic, however the point is the same, which is constantly doubling file size.  Also, the example is lengthy, sorry about that, I could'n find a way to simplify it further.

Preparation:

```
# loading the libraries
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

# preparing the shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326))

# preparing the colors (not really important)
pal.area <- colorNumeric(palette = "inferno", domain = range(nc$AREA))
pal.perim <- colorNumeric(palette = "inferno", domain = range(nc$PERIMETER))
pal.cnty <- colorNumeric(palette = "inferno", domain = range(nc$CNTY_))
pal.sid74 <- colorNumeric(palette = "inferno", domain = range(nc$SID74))
```

Making the leaflet, this section is long, however it's simply 4 leaflet maps created one after another by adding one layer at a time.  It's mostly copy-pasted work:

```
###
one_layer <- leaflet(data = nc) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.area(AREA),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "area") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.area, values = ~AREA,
    opacity = 1, group = "area"
  )  
###


###
two_layers <- leaflet(data = nc) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.area(AREA),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "area") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.area, values = ~AREA,
            opacity = 1, group = "area") %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.perim(PERIMETER),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "perim") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.perim, values = ~PERIMETER,
            opacity = 1, group = "perim"
  ) %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = c("area", "perim"), position = "bottomleft",
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
###

###
three_layers <- leaflet(data = nc) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.area(AREA),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "area") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.area, values = ~AREA,
            opacity = 1, group = "area") %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.perim(PERIMETER),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "perim") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.perim, values = ~PERIMETER,
            opacity = 1, group = "perim"
  ) %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.cnty(CNTY_),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "cnty") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.cnty, values = ~CNTY_,
            opacity = 1, group = "cnty"
  ) %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = c("area", "perim", "cnty"), position = "bottomleft",
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  hideGroup(c("perim","cnty"))
###

###
four_layers <- leaflet(data = nc) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.area(AREA),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "area") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.area, values = ~AREA,
            opacity = 1, group = "area") %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.perim(PERIMETER),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "perim") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.perim, values = ~PERIMETER,
            opacity = 1, group = "perim"
  ) %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.cnty(CNTY_),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "cnty") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.cnty, values = ~CNTY_,
            opacity = 1, group = "cnty"
  ) %>% 
  addPolylines(fillColor = ~pal.sid74(SID74),
               fill = TRUE,
               opacity = 0.8,
               group = "sid74") %>% 
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal.sid74, values = ~SID74,
            opacity = 1, group = "sid74"
  ) %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = c("area", "perim", "cnty", "sid74"), position = "bottomleft",
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  hideGroup(c("perim","cnty", "sid74"))
###
```

Then, you get 4 objects (maps)  we can compare their size directly in R:

```
object.size(one_layer)
301864 bytes
object.size(two_layers)
531144 bytes
object.size(three_layers)
681872 bytes
object.size(four_layers)
828616 bytes
```

The size increase is constant and way higher that what we would expect if the only the data was added instead of all the spatial info.  As a comparison, the initial shape which has 15 fields is of size:

```
object.size(nc)
135360 bytes
```

If we save the maps to HTML, the problem is even more visible:

```
saveWidget(one_layer, paste0(getwd(),"/temp_data/temp/one_layer.html"), selfcontained = F)
saveWidget(two_layers, paste0(getwd(),"/temp_data/temp/two_layers.html"), selfcontained = F)
saveWidget(three_layers, paste0(getwd(),"/temp_data/temp/three_layers.html"), selfcontained = F)
saveWidget(four_layers, paste0(getwd(),"/temp_data/temp/four_layers.html"), selfcontained = F)

file.info(list.files("temp_data/temp", pattern = ".html$", full.names = T))$size[c(2,4,3,1)] %>%
  setNames(c("One Layer", "Two Layers", "Three Layers", "Four Layers")) %>%
  barplot(ylab="size in Bytes")
```

[image]

It's clearly doubling in size.

So, to summarize, is there a way to get leaflet to not reproduced the spatial information when adding multiple fields of data to the same map?

Comment: If you want to let the user choose what information to show (layer), then it’s only possible by adding all the information several times. If yhr user is able to open an attribute table, you could try to Implement a filter function.

Comment: @Jelle, Could you elaborate more on having the user open an attribute table?  I save a csv at the same time I save my html leaflet, but I didn't think with could link the two together.  At the end, I want the user to be able to have a stand alone file (the html) with all the info, if it comes with another file (csv or other) it would be ok.